# How to maintain the size of image while interpolating in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation

I have interpolated my nifti image (mri data) via linear method. but the problem is that field of view in output changes (input is 400*400 but output is 4000*3000 ) I am searching for a way to keep the dimensions while interpolating. Do you may have a solution? 
Thank you

```
t1_ = "name.nii.gz"
img_t1_ = nib.load(t1_)
img_t1_ = np.double(img_t1_.get_fdata())
slice_ = 300
img_t1_ = np.rot90(img_t1_[:,:,slice_,0])
x = np.linspace(0, img_t1_.shape[1],  img_t1_.shape[1])
y = np.linspace(0, img_t1_.shape[0],  img_t1_.shape[0])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = img_t1_
x2 = np.linspace(0, img_t1_.shape[1],  9*img_t1_.shape[1])
y2 = np.linspace(0, img_t1_.shape[0],  9*img_t1_.shape[0])
print(x2.shape[0], y2.shape[0])
tmp_z_ = np.zeros((x2.shape[0], y2.shape[0]))
f_linear = interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='linear')
Z2 = f_linear(x2, y2)
```

Comment: How do you expect to interpolate without changing the image resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by keeping the dimensions, you mean keeping the aspect ratio (i.e. input: 400x400 -> output: 4000x4000). Also, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve with your interpolation. However, depending on the use case, the `zoom` function in `scipy`'s `ndimage` module could do the job. If you chose parameter `order=1`, this corresponds to linear interpolation.

I'm not familiar with the packages you use to import your images. The following example assumes that the image data has been loaded to `img_data`, a two dimensional float array. Just adapt to your use case.

```
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
interpolated_img_data = zoom(img_data, 10, order=1)
```